# Inferred type appears to detect an infinite loop, but what's really happening?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, type-systems, ml, hindley-milner

In Andrew Koenig’s [An anecdote about ML type inference](http://www.usenix.org/publications/library/proceedings/vhll/full_papers/koenig.a), the author uses implementation of [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) as a learning exercise for ML and is pleased to find an “incorrect” type inference.

> Much to my surprise, the compiler reported a type of
>
> ```
> 'a list -> int list
> ```
>
> In other words, this sort function accepts a list of any type at all and returns a list of integers.
>
> That is impossible.  The output must be a permutation of the input; how can it possibly have a different type?  The reader will surely find my first impulse familiar: I wondered if I had uncovered a bug in the compiler!
>
> After thinking about it some more, I realized that there was another way in which the function could ignore its argument: perhaps it sometimes didn't return at all.  Indeed, when I tried it, that is exactly what happened: `sort(nil)` did return `nil`, but sorting any non-empty list would go into an infinite recursion loop.

When translated to Haskell

```
split [] = ([], [])
split [x] = ([x], [])
split (x:y:xs) = (x:s1, y:s2)
  where (s1,s2) = split xs

merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge xx@(x:xs) yy@(y:ys)
  | x < y     = x : merge xs yy
  | otherwise = y : merge xx ys

mergesort [] = []
mergesort xs = merge (mergesort p) (mergesort q)
  where (p,q) = split xs
```

GHC infers a similar type:

```
*Main> :t mergesort
mergesort :: (Ord a) => [t] -> [a]
```

How does the [Damas–Hindley–Milner algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner) infer this type?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is indeed a remarkable example; an infinite loop being detected, essentially, at *compile time*! There is nothing special about the Hindley–Milner inference in this example; it just proceeds as usual.

Note that ghc gets the types of `split` and `merge` correctly:

```
*Main> :t split
split :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
*Main> :t merge
merge :: (Ord t) => [t] -> [t] -> [t]
```

Now when it comes to `mergesort`, it is, in general, a function t<sub>1</sub>→t<sub>2</sub> for some types t<sub>1</sub> and t<sub>2</sub>. Then it sees the first line:

```
mergesort [] = []
```

and realizes that t<sub>1</sub> and t<sub>2</sub> must be list types, say t<sub>1</sub>=[t<sub>3</sub>] and t<sub>2</sub>=[t<sub>4</sub>]. So mergesort must be a function [t<sub>3</sub>]→[t<sub>4</sub>]. The next line

```
mergesort xs = merge (mergesort p) (mergesort q) 
  where (p,q) = split xs
```

tells it that:

- xs must be an input to split, i.e., of type [a] for some a (which it already is, for a=t<sub>3</sub>).
- So `p` and `q` are also of type [t<sub>3</sub>], since `split` is [a]→([a],[a])
- `mergesort p`, therefore, (recall that mergesort is believed to be of type [t<sub>3</sub>]→[t<sub>4</sub>]) is of type [t<sub>4</sub>].
- `mergesort q` is of type [t<sub>4</sub>] for exactly the same reason.
- As `merge` has type `(Ord t) => [t] -> [t] -> [t]`, and the inputs in the expression `merge (mergesort p) (mergesort q)` are both of type [t<sub>4</sub>], the type t<sub>4</sub> must be in `Ord`.
- Finally, the type of `merge (mergesort p) (mergesort q)` is the same as both its inputs, namely [t<sub>4</sub>]. This fits with the previously known type [t<sub>3</sub>]→[t<sub>4</sub>] for `mergesort`, so there are no more inferences to be done and the "unification" part of the Hindley–Milner algorithm is complete. `mergesort` is of type [t<sub>3</sub>]→[t<sub>4</sub>] with t<sub>4</sub> in `Ord`.

That's why you get:

```
*Main> :t mergesort 
mergesort :: (Ord a) => [t] -> [a]
```

(The description above in terms of logical inference is equivalent to what the algorithm does, but the specific sequence of steps the algorithm follows is simply that given on the Wikipedia page, for example.)

Comment: I think it is a stretch to say that type inference "detected" an infinite loop.  Rather, the type system inferred a (perfectly valid) type that differed from the programmer's expectations, which caused him to reexamine his code and detect the infinite loop for himself.  But it is still very interesting!

Comment: @Geoff: Agreed. (I tried to get away with an "essentially" qualifier :p) It is amazing, nevertheless, that type checking enabled the programmer to find an infinite-loop bug at compile-time. This example is also discussed by Mark Jason Dominus in his types talk, here: http://perl.plover.com/classes/OOPSLA/samples/slide061.html

Comment: I learned about this example from a Dominus talk years ago. I started out with a pointer to his notes but took it out because the extra citation seemed rambly: http://perl.plover.com/yak/typing/notes.html

Answer (score 2):

That type can be inferred because it sees that you pass the result of `mergesort` to `merge`, which in turn compares the heads of the lists with `<`, which is part of the Ord typeclass. So the type inference can reason that it must return a list of an instance of Ord. Of course, since it actually recurses infinitely, we can't infer anything else about the type it doesn't actually return.